# Local and synchronized usage

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

After online registration, my mobile app must be able to be used without a network. It consists of a service and a UI, both accessing the same data.

I do not understand how to organize my application.
I known how to record data remotely (on my ROS) and locally but what about the synchronization between the two .realm?
This is should my app manage synchronization between these two db or is there another way?

When I create the user on my ROS, I get a .realm file on the device.
But it is unusable without User.LoginAsync (Incompatible histories exception).

Comment: I assume if you use a Sync Realm offline, then it should work just as well, and eventually when there is network available it will update ROS and local realms.

Comment: This will force my service to connect regularly to my ROS is not it? Depending on the validity of the token if I understand correctly. In this case, my app can not work offline.